# how to merge two countvectorizers when there are duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

Consider this simple example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text1' : ['hello world', 'hello universe'],
                     'text2': ['good morning', 'hello two three']})
    
data
Out[489]: 
            text1            text2
0     hello world     good morning
1  hello universe  hello two three
```

As you can see, `text1` and `text2` share one exact word in common: `hello`. I am trying to create ngrams separately for `text1` and `text2` and I want to concatenate the results together into a countvectorizer object.

The idea is that I want to create ngrams separately for the two variables and used them as features in a ML algo. However, I do want the extra ngrams that would be created by concatenating the string together, like `world good` in `hello world good morning`. This is why I keep the ngram creation separated.

The issue is that by doing so, the resulting (sparse) vector will contain a duplicated `hello` column.

See here:

```
vector = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))

v1 = vector.fit_transform(data.text1.values) 
print(vector.get_feature_names())

['hello', 'hello universe', 'hello world', 'universe', 'world']

v2 = vector.fit_transform(data.text2.values)
print(vector.get_feature_names())

['good', 'good morning', 'hello', 'hello two', 'morning', 'three', 'two', 'two three']
```

And now concatenating `v1` and `v2` gives 13 columns

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
print(hstack((v1, v2)).toarray())

[[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]]
```

The proper text-features should be 12:

`hello`, `word`, `hello word`, `good`, `morning`, `good morning`,`hello universe`,`universe`,  `two`, `three`, `hello two`, `two three`

What can I do here to have the proper unique words as features?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way to tackle this problematic would be to create a custom Transformer that use a `CountVectorizer`.

I would do as follow:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np

class MultiRowsCountVectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.verctorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
    
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        #concatenate all textual columns into one column
        X_ = np.reshape(X.values, (-1,))
        self.verctorizer.fit(X_)
        return self
    

    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        #join all the textual columns into one column
        X_ = X.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
        return self.verctorizer.transform(X_)
    
    def get_feature_names(self):
        return self.verctorizer.get_feature_names()
    
    
transformer = MultiRowsCountVectorizer()
X_ = transformer.fit_transform(data)
transformer.get_feature_names()
```

The `fit()` method is fitting the `CountVectorizer` by treating the columns independently while `transform()` is treating the columns as the same line of text.

`np.reshape(X.values, (-1,))` is transforming a matrix of shape `(N, n_columns)` into one dimensional array of size `(N*n_columns,)`. This ensure that each text field is treated independently during the `fit()`. After that the transformation is applied on all the text feature of a sample by joining them together.

This custom Transformer is returning the desired 12 features:

```
['good', 'good morning', 'hello', 'hello two', 'hello universe', 'hello world', 'morning', 'three', 'two', 'two three', 'universe', 'world']
```

and returning the following features:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

**NOTES**: this custom transformer assume that `X` is a `pd.DataFrame` with `n` textual columns.

**EDIT**: The textuals fields need to be joined with a space during the `transform()`.

Comment: very interesting, thanks! do you mind explaining a little more what is going on here? what is `X_ = np.reshape(X.values, (-1,))` doing exactly? and I assume the DF that needs to be passed only contains the two text columns only?

Comment: I modify my answer to describe this operation. This transformer works with an arbitrary number of text columns.

Comment: thanks antoine this is really great. just a noob question. I see you define a `fit` and a `transform` function, yet you call `fit_transform` in your example. Why is this working?

Comment: The `fit_transform()` is inherited by the class `TransformerMixin` which is simply defining `fit_transform()` as a call to the `fit()`, then `transform()` function. See source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/base.py#L668)

Comment: really cool thanks. one last point that I missed. I get that you reshape all columns into a huge vector of text (smart idea) but why do you need to join the columns then? Are'nt all the text columns included in the same huge vector? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The two operations is different, the data are joined during the transform as we want only one one-hot-encoded vector per line. during `fit()`we are concatenating them as we want to treat each text independently.

Comment: Implementing a custom transformer is a nice solution! However, maybe I'm missing something, but does the resulting array have wrong values?

Comment: My bad, indeed the textual fields need to be joined by a space during the transform. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: this answer might not be very sophisticated, but if I understood correctly your problem it should do its job.*

```
# create an additional column by chaining the two text columns with a fake word
data['text3'] = data['text1'] + ' xxxxxxxxxx ' + data['text2']
print(data)
#             text1            text2                                      text3
# 0     hello world     good morning        hello world xxxxxxxxxx good morning
# 1  hello universe  hello two three  hello universe xxxxxxxxxx hello two three

# instantiate CountVectorizer and fit it
vector = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
v3 = vector.fit_transform(data.text3.values)

# have a look at the resulting column names
all_colnames = vector.get_feature_names()
print(all_colnames)
# ['good', 'good morning', 'hello', 'hello two', 'hello universe', 'hello world', 'morning', 'three', 'two', 'two three', 'universe', 'universe xxxxxxxxxx', 'world', 'world xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx good', 'xxxxxxxxxx hello']

# select only column names of interest
correct_colnames = [e for e in vector.get_feature_names() if 'xxxxxxxxxx' not in e]
print(correct_colnames)
# ['good', 'good morning', 'hello', 'hello two', 'hello universe', 'hello world', 'morning', 'three', 'two', 'two three', 'universe', 'world']

print(len(all_colnames))
# 17
print(len(correct_colnames))
# 12   # the desired length

# select only the array columns where the fake word is absent
arr = v3.toarray()[:, ['xxxxxxxxxx' not in e for e in colnames]]
print(arr.shape)
print(arr)
# (2, 12)
# [[1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]]

# if you need a pandas.DataFrame as result
new_df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=correct_colnames)
print(new_df)
#    good  good morning  hello  hello two  hello universe  hello world  morning  three  two  two three  universe  world
# 0     1             1      1          0               0            1        1      0    0          0         0      1
# 1     0             0      2          1               1            0        0      1    1          1         1      0
```

---

The rationale behind it is: we insert a fake word, like `'xxxxxxxxxx'`, which is close-to-impossible to encounter in a text string. The algorithm will consider it as a real word and therefore will create 1-grams and 2-grams with it.

However, we can eliminate those n-grams afterwards, and all the equal words (like `'hello'` in this case) will not be counted separately for the two text columns - in fact, you can see that in the resulting dataframe, the word `'hello'` appears two times in the second row, and it's not duplicated.

Comment: thanks! This is a nice workaround, but a little on the hacky side perhaps? There is an easy solution in R... I cannot believe this is the first time people think about this?

Comment: Could you link the easy solution in R? Maybe it can be reproduced somehow in Python as well. BTW, another solution could be implementing a custom scikit-learn transformer by defining a custom class, but one should be careful in defining the `.fit` and `.transform` methods to avoid data leakage... Mine is the easiest (although hacky, as you said) solution that came to mind